# Transaction not working in azure cloud service

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have created a azure cloud worker role.
I need to enter data to multiple tables. I am using multiple functions.
I am using transaction scope. But its not working.
How to do that.
The some this is working when I am using local database. But when I am using azure database, transaction is not working.

Comment: What is does your code look like? What error are you hitting?

Answer (score 0):

Transaction Scope allowing multiple connections from an application to query multiple Azure DBs is now available in Preview (Elastic Database Transactions).  Previously this functionality was not available because Azure does not support DTC, but now Transaction coordination can be managed in Azure without DTC.

Detailed documentation is available [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview/).  Note that you will need to work with .Net framework version 4.6.1 to take advantage of this capability.